# What is the purpose of magic try_files statement?

Tags: nginx

Maintaining the system which was setup by a 3rd party found the following in the nginx vhost configuration

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    listen *:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert.key;

    server_name <server-name-here>;

    root   /path/to/vhost/root;

    index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

    error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/domain-name/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/domain-name/access.log combined;

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /stats/ {
        index index.html index.php;
        auth_basic "Members Only";
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/passwd/file;
    }

    location ^~ /awstats-icon {
        alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files /0816f18c2383162111fc93fe015c1607.htm @php;
    }

    location @php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9010;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    client_max_body_size 24M;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*.domain.name';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST';

       satisfy any;
       allow <white-listed-IPs>;
       deny all;
            auth_basic "Members Only";
            auth_basic_user_file /path/to/passwd/file;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files /0816f18c2383162111fc93fe015c1607.htm @php;
            }
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg|pdf)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 1h;
    }
}
```

which looks pretty straightforward to me except this `try_files /0816f18c2383162111fc93fe015c1607.htm @php;` statement. There is no file with that name on the disk. Apparently this is some sort of magic used for monitoring or switching the vhost off, hard to google for it since the filename is totally random string.

Any idea what is that used for?

P.S. We are talking about Linux machine, it also has ISPConfig installed, not sure if that matters. Nginx version was `1.2.0` when I took the machine over.

Comment: The file name is probably intended to be non-existent; it looks like they were simply using it to jump into the `@php` block...which immediately does try_files on the actual uri. Why it was done this way isn't clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One legitimate use for this `try_files` entry is to make it easy to enter site into maintenance mode. Once this file is created on the web server, no PHP scripts are executed, only that particular `.htm` file is displayed.

During the maintenance it would be easier to perform complex updates without making site break in unexpected ways.

The filename is chosen to be this so that it wouldn't clash with any other `.htm` file on the site.

However, this way of implementing maintenance mode would break all other non-HTML content pages during maintenance period, like RSS feeds, sitemaps and JSON APIs.

Comment: This was my thinking as well, though I would choose more speaking filename if setting up something like that. Therefore I though that it might be some sort of best practice which I'm not aware of.

Comment: Well, everybody can have his own ideas of how to name such things. I'm not aware of any best practices, I have named my own maintenance pages `maintenance.html` to be clear.